# allow client to change registry

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, domain-controller, user-permissions

How can I grant user to write to win7 registry. He is in domain win2008 R2. What I must change in group policy to allow access? He is trying to run some portable aplication and without this cant run it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the purposes of granting permissions to the registry, think of it like a file and folder hierarchy.  Registry keys and values, just like files and folders, can have different and separate ACLs controlling who may or may not view, write or them modify, and like files and folders, these permissions are inheritable.

If you can't assign the user local admin rights, as suggested by pauska, you need to track down what registry locations this portable app is trying to access and modify, and set the permissions on those specific locations to be viewable, writable or modifiable (as appropriate) by his user, or possibly even by `everyone`/`anonymous` is the application is particularly insecurely written.

Answer (score 2):

There are probably a TON of different security rights you have to alter to get this working. IMHO - if he's going to be editing the local registry then you can just as well add him to the local administrator group on the PC in question.